# Get value of an input field in Blazor without @oninput

Tags: javascript, c#, html, blazor

I have an HTML `<input>` element that is generated by a Blazor `<InputText>` component.

I am using a JavaScript library to detect when the user scans a barcode. When this event occurs I set the value of the scanned barcode into the `<input>` element.

I want to be aware of this change of value immediately in C#. Normally I'd use `@bind-event:oninput` to ensure I have the current value immediately whenever it changes, but this event isn't fired when the HTML input's value is set via code.

Is there a way to assign a value to an HTML input via JavaScript and then have C# immediately aware of the change and update the property of the C# object the `InputText` control is bound to?

Comment: Could you explain why you are setting a value via JS rather than C#?

Comment: I'm using a JS library to scan a barcode. I have found a workaround for my problem but it is very hacky (luckily this is only a proof of concept). See my answer.

Comment: The simplest way is to set the value on the input, then use `input.dispatchEvent(...)` to send it a `change` or `input` event - that way you don't have to create loads of extra code

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this the following way:

Where you have the value in JS that you want in C#, apply it to a field and call .click() on a button. This button calls a C# method that invokes a JS function that returns the value of the input as a string to your C# method, which you can now use however you want.

While it is a dirty solution, it worked.

I have tried to get invokeMethodAsync to call my C# method directly, but that required it to be static and I simply didn't have the time for this project to do it the proper way.

Comment: Does the js library have some kind of event it fires off whenever the user scans?

Comment: @petermorris yes. It is Quaggajs which calls onDetected. Here is where I wanna pass my barcode to the C# side. I'm thinking using a JS library was probably the first mistake.

Comment: I would have JS call a static C# method every time this event is fired. Then I'd descend from InputText and have it do the following

1: Record that the control is focused using `@onfocus`
2: Record it is not focused using `@onblur`
3: Subscribe to a static event that is triggered whenever that static C# method is 
called.
4: Implement IDisposable so you can unsubscribe from the static event (to prevent memory leaks)
5: Whenever the event triggers and the input is focused, the control should update its value.